# MS Active Directory with Google Authenticator

Tags: active-directory, freeradius, google-authenticator

I am currently designing our new internal IT services, including IAM and e-mail. We currently use more or less no IAM or single sign-on solution. We have a WordPress based website, postfix + dovecot based mail server with separate MySQL user database, we currently rely on local users everywhere.

I would like to change that and implement an IAM solution, I am heading towards Active Directory as it has some great capabilities and is easy to support almost anything including Linux os-level accounts.

For MS Active Directory, we would like to use a combination of a small static password per user (4-8 characters) + 6 numeric characters Google Authenticator one-time-password.

I was wondering if anybody implemented something like that and what would be the best moving forward? I can think of two possible directions, one is to use software such as [AuthLite](http://www.collectivesoftware.com/solutions/authlite), second is to implement FreeRADIUS integrated with Google Authenticator thru PAM and configure Active Directory to use this external [FreeRADIUS](http://www.supertechguy.com/help/security/freeradius-google-auth) server to authenticate against, does anybody know on how to achieve the later?

Comment: FWIW, AD is **not** an IAM system. It's a perfectly fine user directory and can be easily used as an authoritative source of authentication from many different OSes and applications, but it's not IAM.

Comment: Now AD DS + AD FS is a perfectly fine IAM.

Comment: Doesn't AD have ability to support google authenticator out of the box?

Comment: I could not find any tutorial how to configure it, so I believe it does not :-(